# flyway.properties file not working as pom.xml configuration alternative

Tags: java, maven, flyway

I need to set flyway migration and I don't want to put password and username in pom.xml, I created flyway.properties file, but it's not working, I'm getting this error

```
Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:6.5.1:clean (default-cli) on project entesting: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password!
```

flyway.properties file is in same directory as pom.xml

```
flyway.user=sa
flyway.password=passwordForThis
flyway.url=jdbc:sqlserver://172.23.176.144;database=DB_Name
flyway.locations=filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration
flyway.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

pom.xml flyway plugin config:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:sqlserver://172.23.176.144;database=DB_Name</url>
                <user>sa</user>
                <password>passwordForThis</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

To summarize I don't want to add password, username etc. in pom.xml(that works), I want it to be in flyway.propeties.

Comment: As you are using Spring Boot Flyway will take the connection information from the application.properties. No need to define your own property file. Read more here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-a-higher-level-database-migration-tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flyway can be configured in a number of ways beyond directly putting it into the maven pom.xml. See documentation on [configuring the maven plugin](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/#configuration)

The contents of the properties file you showed looks like the contents of a `flyway.conf` file.
Flyway will search for and automatically load the `<user-home>/flyway.conf` config file if present.

It is also possible to point Flyway at one or more additional config files. This is achieved by supplying the System property `flyway.configFiles` as follows:

`mvn -Dflyway.configFiles=path/to/myAlternativeConfig.conf flyway:migrate`

See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/#config-files for more information.

Alternatively for storing the database user and password, Maven `settings.xml` files can also be used:

```
<settings>
   <servers>
       <server>
           <!-- By default Flyway will look for the server with the id 'flyway-db' -->
           <!-- This can be customized by configuring the 'serverId' property -->
           <id>flyway-db</id>
           <username>myUser</username>
           <password>mySecretPwd</password>
       </server>
   </servers>
</settings>
```